# How to place a method that doesn't fit in any class

Tags: java, oop

I'm writing a program to implement a card game, and I'm having trouble figuring out where to place one of the methods: specifically one that checks if one card is greater than another,

```java
    public boolean rankGreater(Card card1, Card card2) {
        return card1.getRankId() < card2.getRankId();
    }
```

The reason I'm having trouble is because I plan to use this method in one of my implementations of the Strategy pattern to handle the behavior of computer-controlled opponents, as well as within my *Round* class that tracks the final winner of each round; and it wouldn't make sense to pass Round all the way into this specific Strategy. Where should I define this method in a way that ensures high cohesion?

I've included a super crude diagram of my class relationships:
[image: imgur link because my reputation is too low]

EDIT: Card is part of an external library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If you defined `Card` yourself

Implement the method inside the class `Card`:

```
public class Card {
  ...
  public boolean rankGreater(Card card2) {
    return this.getRankId() < card2.getRankId();
  }
  ...
}
```

Instead of writing `rankGreater(card1, card2)` you would then write `card1.rankGreater(card2)`.

In java, things like this are usually implemented using the interface `Comparable`. That way, you can use predefined methods like `Collections.sort(...)` and `Arrays.sort(...)`.
Here I implemented `rankGreater` again as an example of how to use `compareTo`.

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Card other) {
    return Integer.compare(this.getRankId(), other.getRankId());
  }
  ...
  public boolean rankGreater(Card card2) {
    return this.compareTo(card2) < 0;
  }
  ...
}
```

## If you cannot change the definition of `Card`

When `Card` is defined in a library, you cannot simple change its definition. Well, in theory you could (only adding methods doesn't break things) but I wouldn't recommend it as you would have to apply your manual changes each time you update or install (e.g. automatically in a build process like `mvn`) the library.

In this case, make the method `public static` and put it in a utility class. If you only need in one other class, you could also put it there and make it `private static`.

Comment: I thought of this but since Card is from an external library, wouldn't it affect the rest of my code? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding how external libraries work.

Comment: @Veins Yeah, if `Card` is defined in an external library this solution presented here isn't really helpful. I just didn't know that `Card` was from a library as it wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: sorry about that, I've edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems sensible to me that you might just implement the Comparable interface inside the Card class itself, so that you could skip the need for a separate `rankGreater` method and just be able to do `card1 > card2`.

You'd have something like this:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Card other) {
    return this.rankId() == other.rankId() ? 0
           : this.rankId() > other.rankId() ? 1
           : -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I forgot to include that Card is part of an external library and I'm not aware of methods to add to such libraries (I've edited the post to add this)

Comment: @RobRuenes *»`and just be able to do card1 > card2`«* I'm pretty sure that you cannot compare objects with `>` in Java, even if they implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @Socowi wow, TIL. Been spending too much time in C++ lately it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on the language you are using.
But generally you want to place it in a static class (C#), or make it a static function (java). Or you can use design patterns if you don't want to be restricted by the language.

To place it in a static class in C#:

```
public static class Utility {
    public static boolean rankGreater(Card card1, Card card2) {
        return card1.getRankId() < card2.getRankId();
    }
}
```

To make it a static function in Java:

```
public class Utility {
        public static boolean rankGreater(Card card1, Card card2) {
            return card1.getRankId() < card2.getRankId();
        }
    }
```

Using design patterns by making it a singleton class which is:

> a class that can have only one object (an instance of the class) at a
>   time. After first time, if we try to instantiate the Singleton class,
>   the new variable also points to the first instance created.

Singleton class is a concept and doesn't rely on the language you are using.
Ex:

```
public class Utility {

private Utility instance;

private Utility () {}; // Making the constructor private prevent other classes from instantiating a new one

public static Utility getInstance{ // This is what other classes use to get the instance of this singleton class
 if (this.instance == null ){
  this.instance = new Utility ();
 }

 return this.instance ;
}

}
```

Comment: Would this be overkill? Though, I already have a Singleton class that implements a random number generator so I guess I could add this to that?

Comment: @Veins Probably it will depend on the name of the class. So if the singleton class is named "Utilities" for example, yes it would make sense to add it as a method inside that class.

Comment: Yes, a singleton is absolute overkill for this as the method `rankGreater` does not have a state. A static method in aby utility class (singleton or not) seems to be the best approach.

Comment: One more thing is that this answer is based on what you asked for (How to place the method). But if Card is not an external library and if you can modify it, the best approach would be to make the Card class comparable and benefit from the predefined methods like @Socowi answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62235323/9988889.